# Set.equals doesn't work : only check the first hashSet

Tags: java, maven, junit

I've a little problem here running my Maven test, my assertEquals(Set1,Set2) doesn't work : for an unknow reason even if Set1 is equals to Set2 it automatically return an assert fail.

I've investigated a little and normally assertEquals(Set1, Set2) should call Set1.equals(Set2) and then Set1.equals(Set2) will compare the elements of the two set between them calling the two methods .hashCode() and .equals(). So i've put some System.out.println to check if everything go as it should. But the function .hashCode is only called one time, i don't know why.

Here some code :

```
System.out.println("assertProblem");
assertEquals(Set1, Set2);
```

.

```
if(Set1.equals(Set2))
    System.out.println("equals");
else
    System.out.println("not equals");
```

The two kind of entities that can contain my Set :

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    System.out.println("hashCode");
    int hash = 1;

    hash *= id;
    if(derogation != null)
        hash *= derogation.getId();
    if(description != null)
        hash *= description.hashCode();

    return hash;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object object) {
    System.out.println("equals");
    [...]
}
-----------------------------------------------
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    System.out.println("hashCode2");
    int hash = 1;

    hash *= id;
    if(derogation != null)
        hash *= derogation.getId();
    if(chemin != null)
        hash *= chemin.hashCode();
    if(userFam != null)
        hash *= userFam.hashCode();
    if(serveur != null)
        hash *= serveur.hashCode();
    if(type != null)
        hash *= type.hashCode();

    return hash;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object object){
    System.out.println("equals2");
    [...]
}
```

The values of my 2 Sets :

```
[{id:3658, derogationId:657, description:description ! 0}, {id:3659, derogationId:657,chemin: chemin0, userFam:User/Family0, serveur:serveur010, type:ecriture}, {id:3660, derogationId:657, description:description ! 1}, {id:3661, derogationId:657,chemin: chemin1, userFam:User/Family1, serveur:serveur011, type:ecriture}, {id:3662, derogationId:657, description:description ! 2}, {id:3663, derogationId:657,chemin: chemin2, userFam:User/Family2, serveur:serveur012, type:ecriture}]
[{id:3658, derogationId:657, description:description ! 0}, {id:3659, derogationId:657,chemin: chemin0, userFam:User/Family0, serveur:serveur010, type:ecriture}, {id:3660, derogationId:657, description:description ! 1}, {id:3661, derogationId:657,chemin: chemin1, userFam:User/Family1, serveur:serveur011, type:ecriture}, {id:3662, derogationId:657, description:description ! 2}, {id:3663, derogationId:657,chemin: chemin2, userFam:User/Family2, serveur:serveur012, type:ecriture}]
```

And the result :

```
assertProblem
hashCode
not equals
```

Can someone give me some help here ?

Thx

Comment: They are : org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet

Comment: If they would be unequal, only `set1.equals(set2)` would be called. My suspicion is that there is something fishy, an element that changed its state (changed hashcode) or whatever.

Comment: I assume your "custom" hashCode method is implemented in a wrong way. Or you add some elements to one of the sets and change its hash/key properties afterwards. If its hibernate make sure both sets are initialized.

Comment: I've edited the first post with values and full code of hashCode(). So you could say me if i did implemented it in the wrong way :)

Comment: I didn't think Set's equals method called hashCode, it should be calling equals(). Your result suggests otherwise though O_o

Comment: It appears your hashCode is only being called once. That is troubling since even for a single check, the hashCode has to be called for both objects. Perhaps this PersistentSet of yours doesn't actually override equals? Try using its hashCode method instead.

Comment: The fact that hashCode is called just once means that the first element of `Set2` that was tested wasn't found in `Set1`. To find an element in a HashSet, first hashCode is used to locate the bin, and then equals is used to test all the elements in the bin. If the bin is empty, equals won't be called. If the compared elements are of different types (you said your Sets contain elements of two types, each having a different hashCode implementation), that explains the behavior.

Comment: @Eran Yes ! its was that ! i've tried to put only element from the same class and it work. But how could resolve my problem then ? Cause i need to have these different classes in my Set :/

Comment: @Antoine In order for that to work, `hashCode` and `equals` of both classes must have the same logic.

Comment: With just 6 elements in each set, I suppose it should be doable to print out the hashCode of each element in each set and compare by hand to see if the problem lies in unexpected differences in the hash codes?

Comment: According to https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/collection/internal/PersistentSet.html, `PersistentSet` does override `equals(Object)`.

Comment: @Eren what do you mean by "the same logic" ? And how could change the method can help if it is only called one time ?

Comment: @OleV.V. mmmhhh ... So the whole problem come from the PersistentSet ... I think i will simplu just cast from PersistentSet to another type of Set to compare it

Comment: Just casting it won't make any difference.  You'd actually have to build new sets, if you want to use `equals` in this way.

Comment: Something like `assertEquals(new HashSet(set1), new HashSet(set2));` sounds like worth trying. A cast alone (as in `(OtherSetType) set1`) probably won’t help.

Comment: yes, rebuild it into a new one you are right :)

Comment: Incidentally, it's not a good idea to multiply a whole lot of stuff together in your `hashCode` methods.  The `hashCode` methods in your examples will heavily favour certain buckets above others.  You're better to add hash codes together, multiplying each by different primes as you go.  If you're using Eclipse, you can get it to automatically generate `hashCode` methods that are far better than the ones you've written.

Comment: @DavidWallace, agree. An easy, readable and fairly good option (as good as Eclipse’s) is `Objects.hash(id, derogation, description)` (provided that derogation and description have good hash codes).

Comment: @OleV.V. Woaw thx guys i didn't knew that :)

Comment: Actually, @Eran, I disagree with your analysis.  Look at Antoine's sets.  There are two different types of elements in there, but everything is still equal to something of the same type in the other set.  So the `hashCode` return values should all match up, even though there are two different `hashCode` methods.  This is really starting to look like a bug in the Hibernate code.

Comment: @OleV.V. Thanks.  I didn't know about that method.  It's much better than the Eclipse way of doing things, because of its readability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thx to Ole V.V. and David Wallace comments i've found what was going wrong.

Eran :

> The fact that hashCode is called just once means that the first element of Set2 that was tested wasn't found in Set1. To find an element in a HashSet, first hashCode is used to locate the bin, and then equals is used to test all the elements in the bin. If the bin is empty, equals won't be called. If the compared elements are of different types (you said your Sets contain elements of two types, each having a different hashCode implementation), that explains the behavior.

Ole V.V.

> According to [Hibernate documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/collection/internal/PersistentSet.html), PersistentSet does override equals(Object).

So i've transform my PersistentSet in HashSet to make it work, thx guys :

```
assertEquals(new HashSet(Set1), new HashSet(Set2));
```

Thx everyone.

Comment: Thanks for sharing what you found out. It could be useful for others searching for a solution for a similar problem in the future. One might consider submitting a bug report to Hibernate …